# Type of account for Secondary replica

Tags: database-replication

1)will this account continue to be used for connections or is it a one time connection? My administrator domain account, which I would like to use, has a password valid for only one month.
2)How do I find out which account was used to connect in the past?

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5IdE.png)